# C#: Is it possible to create a transpose of a matrix using Buffer.BlockCopy

Tags: c#, matrix, transpose

I am using Buffer.BlockCopy to create an N x M matrix (2D array) Y from a vector (1D array) X.

```
double[] X = new double[N];
double[,] Y = new double[N, M];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ii++)
{
    X[ii] = ii;
}

for (int targetRow = 0; targetRow < N; targetRow++)
{
    Buffer.BlockCopy
    (
        X,                                                              // source vector
        targetRow * sizeof(double),                                     // source vector offset
        Y,                                                              // target 2D array
        (targetRow * M) * sizeof(double),                               // target array offset
        ((N - targetRow) > M ? M : (N - targetRow)) * sizeof(double)    // count
    );
}
```

I would like to also use Buffer.BlockCopy to create a transpose of that matrix. I am having difficulty figuring the count portion of the code.

```
double[,] YT = new double[M, N];
for (int targetRow = 0; targetRow < N; targetRow++)
{
    Buffer.BlockCopy
    (
        X,                                   // source vector
        targetRow * sizeof(double),          // source vector offset
        YT,                                  // target (destination) 2D array
        (targetRow * N) * sizeof(double),    // target array offset
        (N - targetRow) * sizeof(double)     // count
    );
}
```

I have tried a number of variations and I have been staring at this for some time. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I would prefer not to use looping. Thank you for any suggestions or help you may be able to provide.

The issue seems to be that I need to traverse all N rows of X yet to create the transpose in the Buffer.BlockCopy I need to stop at M rows.

EDIT:

I think I have figured it out: The Buffer.BlockCopy needs to read as follows:

```
double[,] YT = new double[M, N];
for (int targetRow = 0; targetRow < M; targetRow++)
{
    Buffer.BlockCopy
    (
        X,                                   // source vector
        targetRow * sizeof(double),          // source vector offset
        YT,                                  // target (destination) 2D array
        (targetRow * N) * sizeof(double),    // target array offset
        (N - targetRow) * sizeof(double)     // count
    );
}
```

Comment: Where is `XX` defined?

Comment: My apologies, it should read X rather than XX.

Comment: The elements in the transposed matrix are not sequentially arranged so you cannot copy with `BlockCopy`.

Answer (score 0):

If a `N×M` matrix is stored sequentially by rows like this

```
A = [R1C1, R1C2, .. , R1CM, R2C1, R2C2, .. , R2CM, ... , RNC1, RNC2 , .. , RNCM]
```

then given an index `k=0..N*M-1` the row number and column number is found by

```
i = k/M;  // row #
j = k%M;  // col #
```

To generate the index `k` for the sequential matrix you do `k = M*i+j`. For example the 3rd row (`i=2`) and 5th column (`j=4`) for an array with `M=10` columns is `k=10*2+4 = 24`, so `A[24]` should contain that value.

The index for the transposed element is `k_t = N*j+i = N*(k%M)+(k/M)`. For example with the values above (with rows `N=7`) gives `k_t = 7*4+2 = 30`

So to create a transpose of `A` with `B[k_t] = A[k]` you need

```
for(k=0; k<N*M; k++)
{
    B[N*(k%M)+(k/M)] = A[k];
}
```

Now to use it with `BlockCopy()` you just have to scale it by `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not wish to loop through in the manner indicated. Also, the edited version of the Buffer.BlockCopy that I posted below the question works. I figured it out when I realized I only need M rows.